# Render HTML after Post->Redirect

Tags: javascript, python, html, post, fastapi

I am fairly new to webdev, but after one day of searching I try to get help here.

In my example I have an HTML/js page where input data is collected.
This data is sent to FastAPI using POST method.
In the POST method itself I evaluate the data and return a result value to the html page where it is displayed.

How it approached it:

1. Render HTML/js as GET using JINJA2 templates and collect data

```
def home(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {'request': request})
```

2. Send collected data to endpoint `/eval` as POST using ajax

```
function sendData(){
    var data = ... // some_data    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({data: data}),
        dataType: "json", 
        url:"/eval",
    })
}
```

3. Evaluate data and calculate result in `/eval`
4. From `/eval` redirect to new endpoint `/result` which is defined as GET

```
class Results(BaseModel):
    data: str

@app.post("/eval")
def eval(data: Results):
    # Evaluate data 
    result = data # some evaluation happening here

    # The result is not passed here to keep it simple
    return RedirectResponse(url='result', status_code=303)
```

5. In the `/result` endpoint, render the HTML/js with the result as return value using JINJA2 templates

```
@app.get('/result') 
def result(request: Request):
    result = ... # some result
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {'request': request, 'result': result})
```

I can get to 5 and also print the return value in the python console.
The only thing that does not work is that the HTML/js page is rendered.
It keeps showing the initial HTML/js without the result.

When I directly access the endpoint `/result` I can see both the HTML and a return value.

Any ideas ?
Thanks a lot

**Edit: Solved**
I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905051/fetch-api-post-request-response) that served my purpose

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same HTML/js, you can use a promise with JS, like:

```
fetch('../eval.php', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: data
})
.then(function(response) {
 // Code to show results here
})
```

And in the php function you can return a json formated response like:

```
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
 $answer = $_POST['numberOne'] + $_POST['numberTwo'];
 echo($answer);
}
```

If you want to use another HTML/js, you can redirect to it directly like:

```
header("Location: result.html?answer=". $answer);
exit();
```

And to get the variable you can do something like:

`````
const queryString = window.location.search;

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

const answer= urlParams.get('answer')

````
`````

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am wondering how I translate your solution to my actual problem (I am using fastapi which uses python) ? I added the relevant code snippets above.

Comment: I found a solution based on your recommendation on using fetch. Thanks a lot.